# put textbox and button in mvc razor app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a test mvc project and since it's my 1st time working in mvc environment I am almost lost and is completely different compared to asp.net web forms. 
I am trying to put a textbox and a button on a form, but when I am using `<%= Html.TextBox("name") %>` for textbox for example, the code displays as a text on the screen and is not rendered as a textbox. When I am using html markup for textbox and button I can see the textbox but shouldn't `<%= Html.TextBox("name") %>` be correct way to do that?
Here is what I have here:

```
@{  
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Welcome to my Web Site!";
}
<p>
    ASP.NET Web Pages make it easy to build powerful .NET based applications for the web.    
    Enter your name:  <%= Html.TextBox("name") %>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
</p>
```

Which way should I go, can I go with the standard html format or what am I doing wrong that the textbox from `<%= Html.TextBox("name") %>` doesn't get displayed?
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 6):

You are using ASPX syntax.  For Razor, it would be something like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("TextBoxName")
```

So your code would look like:

```
<p> 
    ASP.NET Web Pages make it easy to build powerful .NET based applications for the web.     
    Enter your name:  
    @Html.TextBox("name")
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /> 
</p>
```

Comment: if I want to use a button next to the textbox, which razor syntax I need to use? Thanks

Comment: @Laziale there is no `HtmlHelper` method for a button.  Typically, you'd just use the HTML markup for a button.  You could always create a custom `HtmlHelper` extension class to generate a button for you.  But nothing out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answers, if you are referencing a Model on your View page, then you can use the Razor HTML Helpers with Lambda expressions.

Updated Example (This update is in response to the Laziale's comment):

In your Models directory you have a User class:

```
namespace MvcApplication.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In your Controllers directory, you have a UserController:

```
namespace MvcApplication.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /User/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

In your Views directory, you have a sub-directory named "User" which contains an "Index.cshtml" file:

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.User
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

MVC/Razor will create the following HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
     <form action="/User" method="post">
      <input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />    
      <input type="submit" />
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I would like to know from where did you get the MvcApplication namespace, because when I am writing that line of code I am getting an error that the name 'MvcApplication' does not exist in the current context. Thanks

Comment: The 'MvcApplication' namespace that I used is an arbitrary name that I chose for the example. In your case, you will use the namespace that your class lives in - I will update my original post for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You use the Razor syntax which is denoted using @ at the start:

```
 @Html.TextBox("name")
```